# How to run shell command inside awk and redirect to another shell command?

Tags: awk, pipe, curl

I want to get particular string from the files downloaded using curl and redirect the downloaded file content to another shell program.
Here is the code :

```
curl "http://file-list-url" -s | awk 'BEGIN {c=0} $0 ~ "FILE:" {urlpos=index($0,"URI=")+5;  fileurl=substr($0, urlpos, 150-urlpos-2);  print fileurl ; curl -s -H  "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36"   fileurl | hexdump -C | head -1  ; print filecontent }'
```

After getting each `fileurl`, I want to download it using curl , get its content, pass to `hexdump` then to `head` and print the final output of `head`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to run `curl` etc. inside of `awk`, use `awk` as a processing step in the pipeline and run the other parts of the pipeline afterwards:

```
useragent='User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36

curl -s "http://file-list-url" |
awk '/FILE:/ { urlpos=index($0,"URI=")+5; print substr($0, urlpos, 150-urlpos-2) }' |
xargs -I {} curl -s -H  "$useragent" {} |
hexdump -C | head -n 1
```

Or, if you want the `hexdump` and `head` to act on each of the secondary calls to `curl`:

```
curl -s "http://file-list-url" |
awk '/FILE:/ { urlpos=index($0,"URI=")+5; print substr($0, urlpos, 150-urlpos-2) }' |
xargs -I {} sh -c '
    curl -s -H  "$useragent" "$1" |
    hexdump -C | head -n 1' sh {}
```

Here we use `xargs` to execute a small shell script that runs `curl` using its only command line argument and that passes the resulting output through `hexdump` and `head`.